# How to enter in textarea in WYSIWYG editor in behat

Tags: selenium, symfony4, behat, mink

I'm trying to insert text into a textarea with a wysiwyg editor (summernote) from a form, i'm using behat featurecontext file for this. The textarea doesn't have a id tag so i need to select the class using javascript code:
 `document.getElementsByClassName('note-editing-area').item(0).innerText="something"`

But when i do this, also the innerhtml is overwritten with the text from innerText.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to set an id or class and select that. If you do not use that it is way more difficult to maintain. You could add this through [twig](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html):

```
{{ form_widget(form.task, {'attr': {'class': 'task_field'}}) }}
```